Why have an error in SQL with adding column?
On mysql site I need to add column  not alowing null and on lines  :
ALTER TABLE quizzes.docs ADD doc_code varchar(10) DEFAULT ‘-’ NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE quizzes.docs CHANGE doc_code doc_code varchar(10) DEFAULT ‘-’ NULL AFTER employee_id;

with error :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line

how to fix this ?
8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

Thanks in advance!

Typing your queries from a macOS computer ? Fix your quotes to use real single quotes: ', not ‘’, programming languages don't like those ones.

if the default is null, leave out the default NULL

This
ALTER TABLE quizzes.docs CHANGE doc_code doc_code varchar(10) DEFAULT ‘-’ NULL AFTER employee_id;

Change into
ALTER TABLE quizzes.docs MODIFY COLUMN doc_code varchar(10) DEFAULT '-' NOT NULL;

But if column is not exist you should add column and change ‘ into '
ALTER TABLE quizzes.docs ADD COLUMN doc_code varchar(10) DEFAULT '-' NOT NULL AFTER employee_id;


The only problem he has is the ' vs ‘, no need to suggest other mods.
